# delete a line after a pattern only if it is blank using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to delete a blank line only if this one is after the line of my pattern using sed or awk 
for example if I have

```
G

O TO P999-ERREUR

END-IF.
```

the pattern in this case is `G`
I want to have this output

```
 G
 O TO P999-ERREUR

 END-IF.
```

Comment: better [edit] to show your attempts and format properly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk -v n=-2 'NR==n+1 && !NF{next} /G/ {n=NR}1' file
G
O TO P999-ERREUR

END-IF.
```

Explanation:

```
-v n=-2    # Set n=-2 before the script is run to avoid not printing the first line
NR == n+1  # If the current line number is equal to the matching line + 1
&& !NF     # And the line is empty 
{next}     # Skip the line (don't print it)
/G/        # The regular expression to match
{n = NR}   # Save the current line number in the variable n
1          # Truthy value used a shorthand to print every (non skipped) line
```

Answer (score 5):

Using sed

```
sed '/GG/{N;s/\n$//}' file
```

If it sees GG, gets the next line, removes the newline between them if the next line is empty.

---

Note this will only remove one blank line after, and the line must be blank i.e not spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ex` (edit in-place):

```
ex +'/G/j' -cwq foo.txt
```

or print to the standard output (from file or stdin):

```
ex -s +'/GG/j|%p|q!' file_or_/dev/stdin
```

where:

- `/GG/j` - joins the next line when the pattern is found
- `%p` - prints the buffer
- `q!` - quits

For conditional checking (if there is a blank line), try:

```
ex -s +'%s/^\(G\)\n/\1/' +'%p|q!' file_or_/dev/stdin
```

Comment: You can replace `foo.txt` with `/dev/stdin`. However it doesn't check for the blank line, let me check that.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/(G.*)\n\s*$/\1/;P;D' file
```

Keep a moving window of two lines throughout the length of the file and remove a newline (and any whitespace) if it follows the intended pattern.